# Why does Sonar throw an parse error on sass files?

Tags: sass, sonarqube, parse-error

These are my two Sass files:

1. Function:

   [image: Function]]
2. List of Variables:

   [image: Var]]

I have no idea how to fix it, maybe somebody can help, because I haven't find any information about it.

Comment: It would be nice to see the code causing these errors.

Comment: The code which cause errors you can see on the screenshots, it underlined with red wavy line.

Answer (score 0):

You use UTF-8 with BOM. Both issues are created on the first line at the first column. On the screen you can see `ï»¿@mixin...` or `ï»¿$navbar...`.

The solution is very easy - use UTF-8 encoding without BOM.

Comment: Could you create a small example project? Please add also your SonarQube server and plugins versions.